# Dynamically Populated GF Dropdown with Events Calendar Pro

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, drop-down-menu, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a dynamically populated GF form that pulls a CPT from Events Calendar Pro. I am trying to sort the events by ascending title and I would also like to hide all past events. I have done a lot of trial and error as I am not a PHP developer. I have been trying to add the sorting & hiding for a while and I am just spinning my wheels at this point. TIA. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code that pulls the CPT and displays it in the dropdown correctly.

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_1', 'populate_posts' );
function populate_posts( $form ) {

foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

    if ( $field->type != 'select' || strpos( $field->cssClass, 'populate-posts' ) === false ) {
        continue;
    }

    // you can add additional parameters here to alter the posts that are retrieved
    // more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

    $posts = get_posts ('post_type=tribe_events&numberposts=-1' );

    $choices = array();

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $choices[] = array( 'text' => $post->post_title, 'value' => $post->post_title,);
    }

    // update 'Select a Post' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be
    $field->placeholder = 'Select an Event';
    $field->choices = $choices;

}

return $form;
```

}

Comment: You can view the form here, click the 'Registering for an event' check-box and the dropdown will appear.
https://conni-outdoors.com/contact/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tribe_get_events() function instead of get_posts()
https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/using-tribe_get_events/

```
<?php
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_1', 'populate_posts' );
function populate_posts( $form ) {
    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
        if ( $field->type != 'select' || strpos( $field->cssClass, 'populate-posts' ) === false ) {
            continue;
        }

        // you can add additional parameters here to alter the posts that are retrieved
        // more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

        // Retrieve all upcoming events
        $events = tribe_get_events( array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'start_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
        ) );

        $choices = array();

        foreach ( $events as $event ) {
            $choices[] = array(
                'text'  => $event->post_title,
                'value' => $event->post_title
            );
        }

        // update 'Select a Post' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be
        $field->placeholder = 'Select an Event';
        $field->choices = $choices;
    }

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried early on to use the tribe_get_events and I was missing something to get it to work.
Your code works, but it does't order the events nor hide previous events. Is there a way to have the start date begin searching by today and all events after today? I've tried a few parameters, but they haven't work as of yet.

Comment: I am revisiting this problem. I would like to display the event date after the post title but I do not know how with the current setup that @dkrystev posted. I have tried a number of solutions, but I have not been successful and frankly, I am not understanding how to add the PHP. Pretty frustrated.

Comment: Hey, @werle77 Thanks for checking out my response. I've prepared another solution below, that you might want to try out.

Comment: I have also changed parameters for the `tribe_get_events` function. According to this article: [link](https://support.theeventscalendar.com/666307-Using-tribe_get_events)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_1', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_1', 'populate_posts' );
function populate_posts( $form ) {
    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
        if ( $field->type != 'select' || strpos( $field->cssClass, 'populate-posts' ) === false ) {
            continue;
        }

        // you can add additional parameters here to alter the posts that are retrieved
        // more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

        // Retrieve all upcoming events
        $events = tribe_get_events( array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'eventDisplay'   => 'list',
            'start_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d' ),
        ) );

        $choices = array();

        foreach ( $events as $event ) {
            // These two lines of code will get the event start date in the specified format
            $start_date = strtotime(tribe_get_start_date($event->ID));
            $start_date_day = date('Y-m-d', $start_date);

            $choices[] = array(
                'text'  => $event->post_title . ' ' . $start_date_day,
                'value' => $event->post_title
            );
        }

        // update 'Select a Post' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be
        $field->placeholder = 'Select an Event';
        $field->choices = $choices;
    }

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dkrystev. Unfortunately, this didn't solve adding the event date to the end of the post title. See https://conni-outdoors.com/contact/   tick registering for an event and the drop down will have the post titles (which currently have the date at the begging of each post title as a quick workaround).